# macOS scan/detect screen in real time

Tags: macos, cocoa

There are some apps which can scan the screen and detect things in real time. For example, the macOS preinstalled app "Digital Color Meter". I can move the cursor and the app detects immediately which color is in the area around my cursor. So my question is, how can I do things like this? How can I "scan" the screen and detect objects or colors in a selected area in real time? I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Digital Color Meter only captures a small square of the screen. If that's all you need, try [`CGDisplayCreateImageForRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services?language=objc) and see if it's fast enough.

If that's not fast enough, look at the `CGDisplayStream` functions, starting with [`CGDisplayStreamCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455170-cgdisplaystreamcreate?language=objc) or [`CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454968-cgdisplaystreamcreatewithdispatc?language=objc). These functions are significantly more complicated than `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect` and you'll have to learn about `IOSurfaceRef` to get at the pixel data from a `CGDisplayStream`.

Comment: But i think its unpossible to all of this in real time like the "Digital Color Meter" app. Or I'm wrong?